# Order posts by most comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

`User` has_many `Post`.

`Post` has_many `Comment`.

How could I query the posts of a user, ordered by number of comments each post has?

As much of an ActiveRecord-esque answer as possible would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the comments count for posts as a `counter_cache` in the `Comment` model:

```
belongs_to :post, counter_cache: true
```

Then in your `posts` table, have a `comments_count` field that's an integer.

From there, it's easy:

```
Post.order("comments_count DESC")
```